# SonataAdmin: add new role from route defined in admin class

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, role

I need to create a new ROLE called **STATUS** to appear in ROLE MANAGER of User CRUD like the image at link 
[see image](http://img30.imageshack.us/img30/5071/5my.png), this roles is based on a custom route defined in the admin class, and a custom controller.

I've resolved modifying the config file adding a `information` parameter with the default list of ROLE, but this will apply to all admin class defined in the service, and I don't want that, I want define the ROLE for a specific admin class, and also that can appear in the role manager in order to be assigned a user.

Any suggestion is welcome

Thanks for help!

These are my configurations:

config.yml

```
#SONATAADMINBUNDLE
sonata_admin:
security:
    handler: sonata.admin.security.handler.role
    information:
        EDIT: EDIT
        LIST: LIST
        CREATE: CREATE
        VIEW: VIEW
        DELETE: DELETE
        EXPORT: EXPORT
        OPERATOR: OPERATOR
        MASTER: MASTER
        STATUS: STATUS
```

AdminClass

```
//..
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\RouteCollection;

class SolicitudMantenimientoAdmin extends Admin
{
    //...
    protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
    {
        $collection->add('status',$this->getRouterIdParameter().'/status');
    }
}
```

Service

```
<service id="sonata.admin.solicitudmantenimiento" class="Minsal\SimBundle\Admin\SolicitudMantenimientoAdmin">
      <tag name="sonata.admin" manager_type="orm" group="Solicitud" label="Solicitud Mantenimiento" />
      <argument />
      <argument>Minsal\SimBundle\Entity\SolicitudMantenimiento</argument>
      <argument>MinsalSimBundle:SolicitudMantenimiento</argument>
</service>
```

Controller

```
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController;

class SolicitudMantenimientoController extends CRUDController {
//..
public function statusAction() {
    //... code here
    return new Response('<html><body>Test</body></html>');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem, I read the documentation deeper ([Role Handler](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html#role-handler)), I made the next changes in the follow file:

**security.yml**

I added a **new role** in the security file, in the **role_hierarchy** section like the follow:

```
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_SONATA_SOLICITUDMANTENIMIENTO:
            - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_SOLICITUDMANTENIMIENTO_STATUS
```

When I added the new role, it appeared in the ROLE MANAGER of User CRUD, like the image at the link [see image](http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/4668/kh7u.png)

and it works!!!...